# How to real rectangle of a cell in Winforms Datagridview rather than the relative GetCellDisplayRectangle()

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

ill just get to the point to save you some time as this might be pretty easy to do:

I am using C#, Winforms.

How can i get the real X,Y,width,height (rectangle) of a cell inside a datagridview, it must also work if the cell is not displayed.

The dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle() only returns coordinates of cells that are fully or partially displayed and only relative to datagridview scroll position.

I want to retrieve absolute positions of cells inside a datagridview relative to their position inside the datagridview (not screen position and not datagridview scrolled view position)

I hope this is all you need to understand my issue.

Best Regards,
Eugen.

Comment: Interesting question.What do you plan to do with the rectangle you find for your invisible cell?

Comment: I am planning to create a mergedCells system for the datagridview therefor, if a cell of 2 mergedcells is invisible but the other one is visibile inside the datagridview i want to still get the entire area of the merged cells for the graphics to draw upon, then, after everything is set the graphics will clip it using the datagridview rectangle (without rowsheaderswidths and columnsheaders height)

Using GetCellDisplayRectangle() system will result in several incorrect calculations for text and other drawable items that should be clipped

Comment: There are no 'invisible' cells. Bur you can make rows or columns hidden. How could a cell in such a row/column have any 'real' rectangle location? Maybe you actually mean only portions that are scrolled out of view? In any case you can loop over all rows/colmns and add up their heights/widths. It is up to you to decide which you want to count.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment TaW but thats a terrible idea, if i have around 2 million rows, each painting process would take such a masive ammount of time the application would be considered broken.

all i want is something like this:
int RowNumber = 800;
int ColumnNumber = 13;
Rectangle cellRect = dataGridView.GetCellRectangle(RowNumber,ColumnNumber);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no implemented way to retrieve the cells absolute position inside a datagridview without either subclassing the datagridviewcell or making a massive calculation of each row height and width untill we get to the cell we want, that also has to take into account if the columns before its owner column are visible or not and all the rows above it are visible or not.

Therefor, the solutions displayed here are not viable as they are very expensive performance wise depending on the datagridview rows and columns count, which in my case there will be plenty of both.

PS: There are other more complex aproaches to get what i want but they dont really fit this questions topic.